# Differences between UART receiver STOP bit implementations

Tags: uart, hardware

Some UART receivers require that the specified number of stop bits are present in the received data.  For example, if the receiving UART is configured for 2 stop bits, the transmitting UART must also be configured for 2 stop bits.  Other UARTs only use the stop bit setting for transmitting, and the receiver is always satisfied with 1 stop bit.  Is there a specification that applies to this behavior?

Answer (score 10):

The stop bit for UART, is equivalent to the idle level on the bus.

If your transmitter sends out 2 stop bits, but the receiver is configured for 1 stop bit, everything will work fine. The receiver sees the first stop bit, finishes its packet, and then waits for the next start bit. The second stop bit is seen as simply a bus idle state.

If however the settings were reversed, transmission included only 1 stop bit, but receive requires 2, things may not work properly, as if two packets are transmitted immediately after each other, only one stop bit is detected. If however the transmitter waits at least one baud period before it sends the next packet, the two devices will successfully be able to communicate, as the extra idle state between packets would be long enough for the receiver to detect a second stop bit.

Comment: I believe OP was asking how one can tell, from the specifications, how a given UART handles incoming data with one stop bit, even though the unit is configured to transmit two.

Comment: @HotLicks And my point is that it doesn't matter how many stop bits are transmitted, as long as it is greater or equal to the specification of the receiver. A receiver technically only ever needs one stop bit, but it may need extra time between packets to avoid buffer overruns. For example, if you send one packet per second at, say 100 baud, that would be equivalent to transmitting 1 start bit, 8 data bits, and 91 stop bits. Only the first stop bit matters, the rest are ignored while the reciever is then waiting for the next start bit.

Comment: It matters if the other end is only transmitting one stop bit, but the receiver demands two.

Comment: @HotLicks indeed it does, which is what the third paragraph explains.

Comment: In principle, *some* receivers might even be satisfied with a partial stop bit (e.g. 0.25 bits) ... or even no stop bits if there are enough bit transitions in the data to keep the timing synchronized